# pandas group by one column, aggregate another column, filter on a different column

Tags: python, pandas

says this is my data.

```
pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [4,4,5,6,7,4,2,3,4, 2,4,4,5,6,7,4,2,3,3,5,5,6], 'num_wings': [2,7,21,0,21,13,23,43, 2,7,21,13,23,43,23,23,23,11,26,32,75,13], 'new_col':np.arange(22)})
```

I would like to do the following.

1. Group by 'num_legs', and compute rolling(3, min_periods =1) (rolling mean of past 3, with minimum one value in rolling 3) for the 'new_col'
2. However when computing rolling(3), I don't want to take all values of new_col in the group, I wanted to take values in new_col, which have num_wings >10.
3. Need a transform for #2 value, i.e, I would like to populate the result in #2 above, for all rows in the df.
4. EDIT - Also, rows that have num_wings > 10, should get a rolling mean ( = previous or next row value, by the group)

How can I do this? Something like below is what I am thinking, but it's incorrect.

```
df.groupby('num_legs')['new_col'].transform(lambda x: df.loc[df['num_wings']>10, 'new_col'].rolling(3))
```

Comment: If there is only 2 values above 10 your desired rolling 3 contains 2?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I updated it, I can you min_periods as 1. yes, rolling 3 can contain 2. My main concern is, as in the question, how to compute the aggregation of a column, filtering for another column and, populating the aggregation for all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df_filtered = df[df['num_wings'] > 10]
df['rolling_mean'] = df_filtered.groupby('num_legs')['new_col'].rolling(
    3).mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

# Forward fill the missing values in rolling_mean for the first two rows of each group
df['rolling_mean'] = df.groupby(
    'num_legs')['rolling_mean'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill())
df['rolling_mean'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

df_filtered is first created by filtering df for rows where the value in the num_wings column is greater than 10. Then, df_filtered is grouped by the num_legs column and a rolling mean is calculated over the new_col column with a window size of 3.

Since df_filtered only contains the rows where num_wings is greater than 10, the resulting rolling mean series will only contain values for the groups where at least one row meets this criterion. Therefore, when the rolling mean series is added to the original DataFrame as a new column (rolling_mean), it will only contain values for the groups where num_wings is greater than 10.

In order to forward fill missing values in the rolling_mean column for the first two rows of each group, the groupby method is used again, this time on the num_legs column only, and the ffill method is applied to each group separately. This ensures that missing values are only filled with the previous value within each group, and not across groups with different values in the num_legs column.

Output:

```
    num_legs  num_wings  new_col  rolling_mean
0          4          2        0      0.000000
1          4          7        1      0.000000
2          5         21        2      0.000000
3          6          0        3      0.000000
4          7         21        4      0.000000
5          4         13        5      0.000000
6          2         23        6      0.000000
7          3         43        7      0.000000
8          4          2        8      0.000000
9          2          7        9      0.000000
10         4         21       10      0.000000
11         4         13       11      8.666667
12         5         23       12      0.000000
13         6         43       13      0.000000
14         7         23       14      0.000000
15         4         23       15     12.000000
16         2         23       16      0.000000
17         3         11       17      0.000000
18         3         26       18     14.000000
19         5         32       19     11.000000
20         5         75       20     17.000000
21         6         13       21      0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you. In the 2nd solution, where you assign the df_filtered group rolling mean to the original df. 
How will this work ? I saw it is working, but not sure how ? Because the df_filtered has less number of observations than df. Also the index doesn't match. the index on df_filtered is the 'new_col', but the index on the original df, is the original ordered index.
How is this assignment working without same number of observations or een without the same index ?

Comment: In the first solution, to the custom function, what gets passed to the df parameter? Is it the original full df that the group by is called on or just one of the group in df (df gets one group each time. Number of times function is called, is the number of groups in df) ?

Comment: I'm confident in the first answer, let me figure out why the second is returning a different output.  I updated my original post explaining how the first answer's function works. Did the first answer give you the expected output?

Comment: @C_Turbo I checked the second answer, where you assign the grouped DF to an actual DF and it is working. I cannot understand how it works, but it is working in fact. Can't figure out how the  grouped one is being matched without index or same number of records. Any ideas on that ?

Comment: let me know if those edits answer your question

Comment: I am curious on below quotes section of the answer on how it works ?  since rolling mean series have different # of records than the original dataframe, and also rolling series index is not same as the original. Hence, in this case, how would the assignment works accurately? .          "Therefore, when the rolling mean series is added to the original DataFrame as a new column (rolling_mean), it will only contain values for the groups where num_wings is greater than 10."

Comment: never mind, noticed that rolling has indices

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [4,4,5,6,7,4,2,3,4, 2,4,4,5,6,7,4,2,3,3,5,5,6], 
              'num_wings': [2,7,21,0,21,13,23,43, 2,7,21,13,23,43,23,23,23,11,26,32,75,13], 
              'new_col':np.arange(22)})

m = df['num_wings'].gt(10)

df['mean'] = (df.rolling(3)
                .apply(lambda w: df.iloc[w.index][m]['new_col'].reset_index(drop=True)
                .mean())
                .fillna(0) )['new_col']

print(df)
```

```
    num_legs  num_wings  new_col  mean
0          4          2        0   0.0
1          4          7        1   0.0
2          5         21        2   2.0
3          6          0        3   2.0
4          7         21        4   3.0
5          4         13        5   4.5
6          2         23        6   5.0
7          3         43        7   6.0
8          4          2        8   6.5
9          2          7        9   7.0
10         4         21       10  10.0
11         4         13       11  10.5
12         5         23       12  11.0
13         6         43       13  12.0
14         7         23       14  13.0
15         4         23       15  14.0
16         2         23       16  15.0
17         3         11       17  16.0
18         3         26       18  17.0
19         5         32       19  18.0
20         5         75       20  19.0
21         6         13       21  20.0
```